# Ruby prints word by word with seconds in between

Tags: ruby

```
para = "do ray me fa so la te do."
para.gsub!(' ', "#{sleep(2)}")
$stdout.sync = true
```

I want that to print out on same line: (do ray me fa so la te do). Below shows column because the "#" greys out entire line.

```
print para
do#sleep(2) 
ray#sleep(2) 
me#sleep(2) 
fa#sleep(2) 
so#sleep(2) 
la#sleep(2) 
te#sleep(2) 
do#sleep(2)
```

First when I call puts, the "do" first appears then it pause a bit then shows "ray" etc on the same line. Is this possible? As a ruby learner, they say you must not "DRY".

Thanks!

Comment: If that is what happens, then of course it is possible.

Comment: Someone devoted this for reasons I do not know. Instead of printing out the entire string, I want it do print out words by words but with few seconds gap.

Comment: I think you have no idea what you're doing. `para.split(' ').each {|word| puts word; sleep(2) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
$stdout.sync = true
paragraph = "do ray me fa so la te do."

paragraph.split.each do |word|
  print "#{word} "
  sleep 2
end
```

Comment: That didn't word. It squeezes all words together also it pauses 16s before showing the complete word. I want to print the "do" first, then the "ray" etc

Comment: @Sylar Do you run this mini program from your command line with `ruby foo.rb`? Than it should work. If you run the script within a editor or IDE, it depends on the settings of that tool.

Comment: Ok that now works but I need the space in between words.

Comment: @spickermann : what is the purpose of `$stdout.sync = true` in your code? I tried this code by remove first line and still it returns the same reuslt.. Can you plz explain what it does? I will appreciate

Comment: @GaganGami : That forces the OS to flush IO output immediately. If you do not do that it *might* happen that your IO is a bit slow, because the OS want to minimize IO operations. Normally this is not a problem, but in this case with a defined `pause` between two `print` operations this *might* be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is replacing a string with another, which includes some ruby code, but since it's will be escaped, it will never executed.

To achieve what you want I would suggest to try this approach:

```
"a b c d e f g".split(' ').each do |s| 
   puts s 
   sleep(1) 
end
```

So for every string you are wanting a second.

Comment: Not every string, but every word in a string. I want the "do" appears first, then the "ray" etc

Comment: @Sylar Sorry I don't understand what you want, if you replace the string you'll get the strings by the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is what's going wrong:

```
para.gsub!(' ', "#{sleep(2)}")
```

This executes sleep 2, which does nothing for two seconds and returns 2. This is just a slow way of doing `para.gsub!(' ', 2)`